# ColdFusion sessions not being timed out

Tags: session, coldfusion, timeout

We have 2 core applications running on our servers on CF 8, and both have the exact same session timeout set in the application CFC (2 hours at the moment). However we're seeing that sessions are spiralling out of control for one of the applications (currently at 120,000+ on one server), lets call it AppA whereas AppB seems fine (and AppB is the one we'd expect a lot more traffic to).

So I did some further digging and found out that most of the sessions for AppA have been idle for many hours with the highest value I've seen so far being over 11 hours.

We're not actually doing that much with sessions so I'm a little confused as to why they're not being timed out as expected. Also I've dumped the `this` scope in the application CFC and it is showing the expected value for sessionTimeout.

The only thing I had noticed is that in one instance we're assigning a variable on the Request scope from a Session variable. If it were a different scope I would maybe think that is causing some sort of reference that GC (or whatever) can't clear.

Comment: Session timeouts are inactivity timeouts, are you sure nothing is touching the cfc for 11 hours?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually turns out the sessions were started from another App which wasn't over-riding the default value in the base Application.cfc (including the application name).

Answer (score 1):

In terms of the spiral, I'd say that's to do with some requests which aren't passing through the CFID/CFTOKEN to maintain the session. This could be web service calls, CFHTTP requests, search engine bots, etc. Sounds like one of your apps is experiencing this. If this is the case then for CFHTTP pass the CFID/CFTOKEN through to maintain sessions. Web services bit more tricky, you'll need to create a 'key' which is passed back and forth, whole separate topic! Bots can be handled by having some conditionals to set the session timeout value.

For the 11 hours, I'd say thats due to it been kept alive by something. Some continual polling? Reocurring AJAX request? It would have to be something that continues to pass the ID/TOKEN through.

Comment: FusionReactor would be a good tool to have in this situation, to see what scripts are running that you don't know of.

Comment: Yeah I've done some more digging and found that the majority of sessions there are idle for the entire time they've been up so that points towards bots to me. We have some basic checking for crawlers on this app but on the other app we have some more aggressive checks for spam bots, so I'll move those across to this app too I think.

Answer (score 0):

I used to get server lockups in CF6.1 when I was persisting CFCs in the application or session scopes. Now I instantiate them in the request scope and the lockups stopped happening (with no noticeable performance drop). Maybe you have a similar issue.